# Rooting Stock Firmware - GSII with NFC

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-2, stock-android, odin

I have a Galaxy S2 with NFC (GT-I9100P) and I wish to have root access to properly administrate my phone.

I've been looking at various forum posts on different sites and I've just been getting more and more confused as to what I need to do.

From what I understand, I need to flash an unsecure kernel to the phone (with ODIN) to get root access, then I can flash the stock firmware back onto the phone and retain root access. Is this correct?

Further information: 
My baseband version is `I9100PBVLP7`

kernel version: `3.0.15-I9100PBVLPA-CL364024dpi@DELL169 #3`

and my operator is Orange UK.

I've managed to obtain the firmware version that is on my phone already through sammobile.com, I just have no idea what I need to do next.

**Reward**
If anyone can help me to get root access on my stock firmware I will give them as much bounty as I can when the question is eligible for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is root access, try flashing the [Siyah kernel](http://gokhanmoral.com) via ODIN. Ensure you get the S2 version, as the dev has one for the S3 as well. Also, you will need the TAR version as you will flash it via ODIN (at least for the first time). Later instances, you can get the ZIP format and flash it via CWM (ClockworkMod recovery, which is built into the kernel). Apart from features like more processor steps, you can also overclock/underclock, adjust various parameters and have features like Backlight Notifications.

Since you will flash this kernel, you DO NOT need to flash the firmware. You can keep the stock firmware and your data intact. This kernel automatically installs root access so your primary requirement is also fulfilled.

As with all operations, ensure you have an off-site backup of all your data.

As an aside, once you install the kernel, get the [ExTweaks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.darekxan.extweaks.app) app from the market which is designed especially for this kernel and offers a GUI/frontend to access many under-the-hood features.

Assuming you have all the drivers installed, here's how you go about it:

1. Download the TAR file of the Siyah kernel. Note that the latest series is for ICS, in case you're running Gingerbread, search for and download the appropriate older version of the kernel.
2. Start ODIN and connect your phone via the USB cable AFTER you enter DOWNLOAD MODE (Press Vol down + HOME + POWER button simultaneously for a few seconds after completely shutting down phone. At the warning screen hit Vol UP to confirm entry to download mode).
3. Once connected, you should see a COM port number with a yellow background.
4. In the ODIN program, press the PDA button and point to the TAR file.
5. make sure ONLY Auto-reboot is ticked and then click START.

If all goes well, you should see a green box with PASS! shown after which your phone will boot up. It may take a minute or two, so don't panic.

Refer to the FAQ and the respective threads on XDA-Forums for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and the extra details. Would you mind giving me a quick explanation on how to install the Siyah kernel with ODIN please? I just want to be certain I'm doing things correctly.

Comment: Well that was easy, thank you very much. It wasn't very exciting but I'm not sure what I was expecting haha. I'll have to look around and see what else I can do with my root privileges. The bounty will be yours tomorrow.

Comment: If you are interested, use the CWM app to make FULL backups (nandroid). A lifesaver. Also, you can use this CWM app to boot into RECOVERY or DOWNLOAD mode with a tap - no need for a combination of keys.